# Memory problems with customized dialogs

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a utterly customized dialog for my application (incluing title, buttons and so on). I have accomplished that extending the Dialog class and it's displayed and works properly, but it leaks all of the memory it consumes when is created.

This is the core of it:

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    public MyDialog(Context context, String title) {
        super(context, R.style.MyDialog);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    }   
}
```

and I create an instance of it in this way, within an Activty:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this);
dialog.show
```

It's really weird that you have to pass the reference of the Activity, instead of Context, when that is something strongly inadvisable, according to android engineers:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

I have tried to unbind callbacks of the dialog view, prior to a System.gc(), in this way:

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null); 
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}


 ...

 unbindDrawables(dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_container));
```

It has some effect, some memory is released, but not all.

I have recently also had memory problems customizing rows for a ListView, and I think that they are related.

Am I missing something? Am I making a terrible mistake? or is it something usual on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [`recycle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) method in your unbindDrawables method.

And why don't you pass application context instead of activity to MyDialog constructor? This way:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I'll see what happens with recycle, thanks. About application context, it's just the weird thing. If you pass application context when you create a Dialog, you get an exception: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26833): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
You have to pass a reference to the activity in order to make work the Dialog, and what's more, it's not documented, Android API says nothing. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog(android.content.Context)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, that's an old bug. Well then, ensure you do not save any reference to the activity passed to the constructor.

Comment: recycle() didn't work and I don't save any reference to the activity in my MyDialog class. Anyways, a reference to the activity is saved in Dialog class, look at its code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/Dialog.java#Dialog so, in the end, I think there's no solution for this problem. Dialogs in Android are only appropiate using their native UI, since it consumes little memory. Anyways, you can build your own dialogs by yourself, but is disappointing. Thank you

Comment: By the way, do you call `Activity.removeDialog(int)`?